# React Fire on Change event on load

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that dynamically builds check boxes, from the result of an API call.
I am selecting the first radio button in a group, as a default, when the component is created.

Based on what radio button is checked/selected the page displays differently. So the radio button is selected after the page loads, but the onChange function does not get fired to display the page correctly. I am looking for a way to fire the onChange event after loading, API fetch, and displaying the radio buttons.

Comment: Do you have some React code which demonstrates what you've tried and what you're trying to do? There's no `onload` event for input elements so you'll have to simulate it yourself. A straightforward solution might be to call the `changeHandler` or similar function that you assign to `onChange` as soon as the you get data back from the API, since that's the earliest you'll know what the first radio button actually is. It's hard to suggest anything more without seeing what you're already got.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you helped me figure it out.  In the final line of my useEffect hook, I click the first radio button in the group. That both sets the default and fires the change event. I tried setting it to check but that did not fire the change event.

```
useEffect(() => {
  .
  .
  document.getElementsByName('rbImageGroup')[1].click();
}, []);
```

Comment: you're direction using DOM manipulation here? Did you look at React.ref?